# Extract wrong data from a frame in C?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, frame

I am writing a program that reads the data from the serial port on Linux. The data are sent by another device with the following frame format:

```
|start | Command | Data               | CRC  | End |
|0x02  | 0x41    | (0-127 octets)     |      | 0x03|
----------------------------------------------------
```

The Data field contains 127 octets as shown and octet 1,2 contains one type of data; octet 3,4 contains another data. I need to get these data.

Because in **C**, one byte can only holds one character and in the start field of the frame, it is 0x02 which means STX which is 3 characters.

So, in order to test my program,

On the sender side, I construct an array as the frame formatted above like:

```
char frame[254];
frame[0] = 0x02; // starting field
frame[1] = 0x41; // command field which is character 'A'
..so on..
```

And, then On the receiver side, I take out the fields like:

```
char result[254];
// read data
read(result);
printf("command = %c", result[1]); // get the command field of the frame

// get other field's values
```

the command field value (result[1]) is not character 'A'.

I think, this because the first field value of the frame is 0x02 (STX) occupying 3 first places in the array frame and leading to the wrong results on the receiver side.

How can I correct the issue or am I doing something wrong at the sender side?

related questions: 
[Parse and read data frame in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500567/parse-and-read-data-frame-in-c) 
[Clear data at serial port in Linux in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531779/clear-data-at-serial-port-in-linux-in-c)

Comment: What *does* the buffer contain? What function do you call to perform the read? (That is clearly not a `read` system call.) Have you verified the serial link with a terminal application?

Comment: `STX` does not take 3 bytes; all characters take 1 byte. Some characters (like `STX`) just have longer names.

Comment: the full code of read() function is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500567/parse-and-read-data-frame-in-c.
I think so too. If I call result[1], the value should be 0x41 which means 'A', right? But it is not. I returns a strange value. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: What value *are* you getting?

Comment: I got a '?' which means an unknown value.

Answer (score 0):

If your program actually contains

```
read(result);
```

then you need to add

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

at the top, to get the function prototype for `read`. Then you need to `open` the serial port and pass the resulting file descriptor to `read` along with your buffer, so it knows what to read. See `man 2 read` and `man 2 open`.

Comment: If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500567/parse-and-read-data-frame-in-c you'll see that his read function is OK.